# Ability To Filter Posts Based On User's Last Seen Status

Tags: feature-request

I enjoy perusing older questions and providing an answer regardless of age.

A feature proposed would allow one to filter questions based on last `seen` time of (1-week|1-month|3-months...1-year...), of the poster's status, to provide the user with information on the status of the user along with other variables.

---

Why are the user's of SO presented with information like last viewed, last seen, and other attributes, yet there is no way to interact with the data in that fashion?

As mentioned in my comments, this doesn't address any issue about users and how they answer questions; a person should be free to answer questions as they see fit and be given tools to make their own **informed** decision as such.

No more no less.

Comment: But you should be posting answers for the community and future readers, not OP... Sure you may never see that green tick, but who cares?

Comment: @Kyll as I said I enjoy answering older questions...this is just a feature request. A user can look at an older post and click on the user to get that info regardless...why is it not made available during searches if needed?

Comment: To follow up a little on what Kyll said, what benefit does this bring to the community? As you said, if you really want to know that information it's a click or two away. On top of that, even if the user was last seen five minutes ago, it doesn't necessarily mean anything. I only see this really helping people who _want_ recognition from the OP by giving them a chance to see if the OP has been online recently or not, and it still might not help them a ton. This could actively deter users from answering questions where the OP hasn't been online in a long time.

Comment: @Kendra if there is an issue with users not answering older questions, that should be addressed by something other than denying a feature request found on any modern spreadsheet.

Comment: As the one suggesting the feature, you should be telling us why we need it and why it'll be worth any potential issues pointed out to you. "That should be addressed some other way" is not what I would call a good answer to someone pointing out a potential issue with your question. _Sell us the feature, OmegaMan._ Sell why the site needs it and how it will improve things and why issues brought up either aren't issues or are worth it. Bonus points if you can gather evidence of how it will help, though I'm not sure what evidence you could provide for this particular request.

Comment: This is one of those things that a lot of people secretly want to have, but nobody has the balls to actually request it since it's so called "anti-community". Others include the ability to filter out low-rep users, users who don't accept answers.

Comment: In other words, it is custom to downvote anything that even hints at being "anti-community" even if it improves the quality of the user's experience on the site.

Comment: @Mysticial:  Personally I don't see this request as "anti-community"; I just see it as not having enough value to justify putting something else on hold.  Being able to see the most active users' posts would be nifty, but why would we really need it around when we could have [Documentation or major project here] a few moments sooner?

Comment: @Kendra and all, I just want the toolset which is given to the people who answer questions expanded. No tool should have to be *justified* or even sold. There is no empirical evidence which will satisfy people on why filter's should be put in place or not......

Comment: You're asking for the team to take the time to implement your feature. They are already working on a lot of other things, as Makoto mentioned in their comment, so _why should the team take time to implement this?_ That you "want" it is not a reason for the team to drop other projects or bug fixes or what have you to work on _this_ feature.

Comment: Think of Meta as the guy in charge of the project that you have to run any features you want to add past. (If you don't have one of these guys, I envy you. We have an entire group of them.) Convince the guy the project needs that feature, and why they should put time and money into implementing it. Give a compelling argument, be prepared for folks to poke holes in your feature, and have a lot of duct tape on hand to try to patch said holes. There will always be features to add, tell us why yours should take priority or be on the list at all.

Comment: @Makoto Let's put aside the anti-community aspect for a sec. If someone wants feedback on their answers, this is certainly a something that has value. It's a statistical fact that questions asked by inactive users are less likely to respond to answers. So if you're after rep/accept-marks, or just the feeling that you helped the OP, there is value to this. A similar thing applies to other similar requests. For example, the ability to filter out 1 rep users would drastically reduce the amount of trash that fills up my homepage. But it's also anti-community. So it will never be implemented.

Comment: the op isn't the only user who can provide feedback on answers.

Comment: @Mysticial:  I don't disagree that it would be nice to have a tool like that, but my main point wasn't if it had value at all, it was if it had enough value to justify putting that in pipeline as opposed to something else.  It's tough to garner up a wide enough audience that would effectively use it (high-rep users are a small amount), so I personally wouldn't see it being worked on.  To your other point, I would be happy to discuss the filters with you at a later date, since I see both pros and cons of both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until this feature is implemented (despite what all the voters and commenters think) you can easily query for such posts with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Specially because you're looking for older posts, it doesn't really matter that The Stack Exchange Data Explorer is only updated once per week.

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/515183) shows all questions in the haskell tag from users that have not accessed the site since last year.

```sql
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , u.lastaccessdate 
     , u.id as [User Link] 
from posts p 
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
where p.posttypeid = 1 --Q
and u.lastaccessdate < dateadd(yy , -1, getdate()) -- one year ago
and p.tags like '%<haskell>%' -- tags
and closeddate is not null    -- not closed
order by u.lastaccessdate  desc
```

[image: result of posts with users that were last seen a year ago]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to create the SQL. I appreciate that.